# SQL - If id exists in table1, then insert record into table2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem. I have an accounts and a scoreboard table and I try to reset all values on the end of the month in the scoreboard by inserting a new record with the value 0.

```
SET @mid = (SELECT MAX(id) AS mid FROM accounts);

WHILE (@mid > 0)
BEGIN
    IF @mid NOT IN (SELECT id FROM accounts) DO CONTINUE;
    INSERT INTO scoreboard("uid", "balance", "date") VALUES (@mid, 0,(SELECT CURRENT_DATE()));
    SET @mid = @mid - 1;
END
```

But whatever I try it breaks and I have no idea why.

MySQL: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

MariaDB: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1

### Example:

accounts

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Play_it |
| 3 | User2 |

scoreboard

| uid | balance | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2021-03-09 |

### Expected:

scoreboard

| uid | balance | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2021-03-09 |
| 1 | 40 | 2021-03-31 |
| 3 | 30 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-04-01 |
| 3 | 0 | 2021-04-01 |

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
insert into scoreboard (uid, balance, date)
    select a.id, 0, curdate()
    from accounts a;
```

This inserts a new row in `scoreboard` for each row in `account`.

Comment: that really work perfectly for me. Thanks